# Search for a dynamic pattern in a file in a file and replace it with variables

Tags: text-processing, awk, sed, sql

I have written the below commands that will generate three different shuffled vales

```
 A=`echo 'abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz' | sed 's/./&\n/g' | shuf | tr -d "\n"`
        B=`echo 'ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ' | sed 's/./&\n/g' | shuf | tr -d "\n"`
        C=`echo '123456789' | sed 's/./&\n/g' | shuf | tr -d "\n"`

$ echo $A$B$C
zvjmaqwxgchylentifdoprkubsUFTCQEMZKVOLBWYJRPSDHIGXNA729314856

$ echo $C
729314856

$ echo $A$B
zvjmaqwxgchylentifdoprkubsUFTCQEMZKVOLBWYJRPSDHIGXNA
```

One is Alpha numeric, one is numbers and one is alphabets.

I also have a package.sql file which has below patterns.

```
grep TRANSLATE package.sql
         RETURN TRANSLATE(p1_value,'0123456789', '0875642139');
         RETURN TRANSLATE(p2_value,'0123456789', '0875642139');
         RETURN TRANSLATE(p3_value,'ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZabcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz','ZYXWVUFEDCBATSRQPONMLKJIHGzyxwvufedcbatsrqponmlkjihg');
         RETURN TRANSLATE(p4_value,'ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZabcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz0123456789','ZYXWVUFEDCBATSRQPONMLKJIHGzyxwvufedcbatsrqponmlkjihg0875642139');
```

A brief about the above output is, First Part of TRANSALTE lines should remain as it is. (i.e) value in (single quotes)after `p*_value` will be static and it shouldn't be changed, whereas the value in (Single Quotes) after that static value will be dynamic in all the occurences of that TRANSLATE line. I need to change that dynamic part with the Shuffled values I get every time (i.e) with the output of $A$B$C or $A$B or $C.

That values needs to replaced in that package.sql file.

Answer (score 0):

If and only if the values are actually alphanumeric and the occurrences of these strings should *all* be replaced in the file this should work (untested):

```
sed -i -e "s/0875642139/${C}/;s/ZYXWVUFEDCBATSRQPONMLKJIHGzyxwvufedcbatsrqponmlkjihg/${A}${B}/;s/ZYXWVUFEDCBATSRQPONMLKJIHGzyxwvufedcbatsrqponmlkjihg0875642139/${A}${B}${C}/" package.sql
```

Comment: May be possible first part is not static.

Comment: Please update your question to include this. It makes a *big* difference to the implementation if you mean what I think you mean.

Comment: It's not my question just a comment that it is unclear.

Comment: @10b0 The command which you have given will work if those values are static,
But assume, we have changed it now with shuffled values using your SED command. for the next execution the values wont be same right? So It will fail for the second execution,

Comment: @PRY First Part of Alphanumricals or whatever is static (i.e) value after p*_value will be static and value in (Single Quotes) after that static value will be dynamic. in the below patterns. 
  RETURN TRANSLATE(p1_value,'0123456789', '0875642139');
         RETURN TRANSLATE(p2_value,'0123456789', '0875642139');
         RETURN TRANSLATE(p3_value,'ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZabcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz','ZYXWVUFEDCBATSRQPONMLKJIHGzyxwvufedcbatsrqponmlkjihg');
         RETURN TRANSLATE(p4_value,'ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZabcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz012345678

Comment: @sabarishjackson your first comment says that these will change after each cycle, and second comment says that these will be static.

Comment: @PRY First Part of Alphanumricals or whatever is static (i.e) value in (single quotes)after p*_value will be static and value in (Single Quotes) after that static value will be dynamic in all the occurences of that TRANSLATE line. Hope this clarifies, I need to change that dynamic part with the Shuffled values I get every time (i.e) $A$B$C

Comment: @sabarishjackson Again, **please update your question.** It is much easier to answer a question which is coherent than one which is spread around comments.

Comment: @I0b0 Question is edited. Hope it is clear now.

Comment: You may have wanted to use the `y` command rather than the `s` command is `sed`... But I'm not sure.

Answer (score 0):

```
grep TRANSLATE p.sql
| sed -E 's_translate\("(.*)","(.*)"\);_"s/\1/\2/"_' \
# e.g. match the line, and create a sed replacement  "s/012/210/"
| xargs -I% sed -i -e "%" file
```

I think the key thing you need to use is regex grouping.

You can be very specific about what you match, and then include most of it in the output by reference.

`sed 's#(common_str[(][keep class 0-9]+",")[replace class]+#\1replacement str#'`

```
sed 's#
(common_str[(][keep class 0-9]+",")[replace class]+
#
\1replacement str
#'`
```

Answer (score 0):

You may follow the approach (bash shell)

First create appropriately named variables, generated variables, and their shuffled counterparts.

Then run the sed command.

```
num=`LC_ALL=C printf '%s' {0..9}`
A2Z=`LC_ALL=C printf '%s' {A..Z}`
a2z=`LC_ALL=C printf '%s' {a..z}`

 alpha=${A2Z}${a2z}
alnum=${alpha}${num}

 num_shuf=`echo "$num" | fold -w 1 | shuf | tr -d "\n"`
 alpha_shuf=`echo "$alpha" | fold -w 1 | shuf | tr -d "\n"`
 alnum_shuf=`echo "$alnum" | fold -w 1 | shuf | tr -d "\n"`

 sed -e "
    /TRANSLATE/! b

    # numeric
    /,'$num',/ s/'[^']*'/,'$num_shuf'/2

    # alphabetic
    /,'$alpha',/ s/,'[^']*'/,'$alpha_shuf'/2

    # alphanumeric
    /,'$alnum',/ s/,'[^']*'/,'$alnum_shuf'/2
 " input.sql
```